# What does it mean to say R[A,B] where R is a ring and A, B are square matrices with entries in R?

Tags: ring-theory

$R[A]$ makes sense when $A$ is a square matrix but what is $R[A,B]$?

Comment: The explanation given below is plausible, but it is entirely possible an author could use it in completely different way. Where and how was the notation used? Without this context, the question could be pointless, no better than making posters guess.

Comment: Have a look at example 12 in these notes which makes R[A]  clear but what about R[A,B] which is mentioned in exercises https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/44028

Comment: I can’t find the string $R[A, B]$ anywhere in the document, nor do any of the four occurrences of the word “exercise” seem relevant.  So, that is not super helpful...

Comment: see q2ii) here (i think part of the challenge is that the author never defines this) https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/44029

Comment: OK! Got it. Yes, then the interpretation below is correct, and the author is at fault for glossing over this issue.  I don't think the author adequately explains the free algebra in noncommuting variables.

Answer (score 3):

It is the ring of $R$-linear combinations of arbitrary products of $A$ and $B$. This will contain elements like $A^2B-B^2A$ and $B^2A^3BA+AB+B^2$. This is not a quotient of the usual polynomial ring in two variables, but it is a quotient of a polynomial ring in two noncommuting variables.